# I need to update only user name in my app using Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
async function update(id, userParam) {

    const user = await User.findById(id);

    // validate
    if (!user) throw 'User not found';
    if (user.username !== userParam.username && await User.findOne({ username: userParam.username })) {
        throw 'Username "' + userParam.username + '" is already taken';
    }

    // hash password if it was entered
    if (userParam.password) {
        userParam.hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userParam.password, 10);
    }

    // copy userParam properties to user
    Object.assign(user, userParam);

    await user.save();
}
```

When I send an update request it updates everything in the body. I only need to send `userid`, `username` and `user role` and  `update` to update only those fields. I am very beginner.PLEASE help me to solve my issue

Comment: Please provide your frontend code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user.username = user.userParam;
This is the key Line I needed.It solved my issue....Although it's simple answer,it may be useful to some of the beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the document and update the field what you want by using "updateOne". for example, here I am going to update User collection's username only. mongodb's "updateOne" will fulfill that task here basically updateOne has 3 parameters.

search the document you can use any filed here I have used the _id field. 
`{ "_id": "232323"}`
second parameater is `{$set:{"username":"kalo"}` this will set the new value.here you can use any number of fields.

`User.updateOne({ "_id": "232323"},{$set:{"username":"kalo"}})`

For More [mongodb doc](http://www.mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne.html)

If you are using Mongoose nodejs mongodb ORM read [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). This doc says the same thing that I explained.

In your case you can simply use like below instead of `await user.save();`

`await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userid }, { username : username , userid: userid,userrole:userrole})`

**use the User not user**

Comment: I think it could be mongoose, he's using .findById, .findOne and .save.

Comment: YES,I am using Mongoose

Comment: Please provide me a solution